# Python using exit(number) to retrieve a Output

Tags: python

I have a simple script that i use to invoke another script, which succeeds returns an id. Atm the most convenient method i see is as follows.

```
#scriptA.py
x =doOperations(x=1231)
exit(x)
```

.

```
#scriptB.py
result = procScriptA.returncode()
```

Is there any harm in doing that, i kinda have the feeling that i am exploiting the exit functionality, but is there any other way without outputting to **stderr** or **stdout**?

I read this already: [Best way to return a value from a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231415/best-way-to-return-a-value-from-a-python-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On many operating systems, `sys.exit()` can only return integers between 0 and 127. It's primarily intended for signalling whether the command completed successfully (by returning 0) or encountered an error (by returning another value), not for passing back a numerical result.

Use standard output to return results.

Comment: if i use a standardoutput, i can't use any print statement before that, as it will be in the output too